# How to dynamically add a key:value property to c++ class, then make it accessible as class.property

Tags: class, dynamic, properties, key-value

In Python I have a flag class that I have found very useful. I'm newbe to c++, and can not seem to replicate this python functionality in c++. Rather than put up c++ code that didn't work, here's what I am looking to replicate, and I need some suggestions on where to go, templates, virtual, or ??

*The requirement is being able to dynamically alter the members of the class, in python it's modifying the **dict** element of the class it's self that enables this.*

In python:

> import sys
>   args = []
>
> ... loads up args[] with keys:values looping through sys.argv[] ... blah blah blah
>
> class Flag:
>
> def __ init __(self, **args):
>
> self. __ dict __.update(args)
>
> now we enable flag.dynamicproperty
>
> flag = Flag(**dict(args))

An example of use:
$ python script.py somedesc1 someval1 somedesc2 someval2

**What this does is enables me to pass in parameters, as above, from the command-line and assign any number of them on-the-fly**, and make then accessible by a flag.property (eg flag.somedesc1) call which returns somval1. Another way to maybe think about this is dynamically adding a key:value property to a C++ class.

An example of use in python code :

> if flag.somedesc1 != '10': print someval1

I can't seem to make a comparable c++ work. I've looked into polymorphism, but these have to be assigned dynamically and then be accessible as a property of the class.

Ideas??? Surely c++ can do this, I'm just not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is the solution I worked out; haven't tested it yet, but should work close enough to fit my needs using this format

**flag.find(filename)**

enum { filename, workers, runtime };

class flag {

```
vector<string> helplist;
```

public:
    int add(int argc, char *argv[], string flag, string value, string description) {

```
    string flagvalue;
    flagvalue = value;
    helplist.push_back(description);
    for (int i; i < argv.length(); i++) {
        if (argv[i]==flag) {
            flagvalue = argv[i+1];
        }
    }
}
void showhelp() {
    for (int i; i < helplist.length(); i++) {
        cout << helplist[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

};

Comment: You should normally test the solution *before* posting it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this in C++.  In C++, the members of a class are defined 100% at compile time.  You cannot add any at runtime.  The way to do this in C++ would be to have a member variable that's a `map<string,string>` that holds the key/value pairs, and then have a function `string getVariable(string)` that returns the value in the dictionary for that key.

Comment: Initally I was trying to use a vector<string> as the dynamic content holder, I just couldn't figure out a way to tie it back to the object and give it the name for the key. I'll try to work out something with the map<string,string> and getVariable(string) as you suggest.

Comment: Can you think of any way to create a dynamic enum?